# Is there any way to use Kotlin Anko Alertdialog with handling screen rotation changes?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-alertdialog, anko

Using Anko library is pretty easy, but when i rotate screen, my dialog dismisses. The only way how to avoid this is to use child of `DialogFragment()` with method `show(fm, TAG)`.

So we need to override method `onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog` which returns `Dialog` instance. But Anko's `alert{ }.build()` returns `DialogInterface` instance

So, is there any way to use anko in this situation?

```
alert {
        message = "Message"                   
        positiveButton("OK") {
            //stuff
        }
        negativeButton("NOT OK") {
            //stuff
        }
}.show()
```

**EDIT**

So, that what I did.
I've created abstract *BaseDialogFragment*:

```
abstract class BaseDialogFragment : DialogFragment() {

    abstract val ankoAlert: AlertBuilder<DialogInterface>

    protected var dialogListener: DialogListener? = null

    protected val vm by lazy {
        act.getViewModel(DialogViewModel::class)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        dialogListener = parentFragment as? DialogListener
    }

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog =
            (ankoAlert.build() as? Dialog)
                    ?: error("Anko DialogInterface is no longer backed by Android Dialog")
}
```

Then I've created some dialogs, like that:

```
class MyDialogFragment : BaseDialogFragment() {

    companion object {
        fun create() = MyDialogFragment ()
    }

    override val ankoAlert: AlertBuilder<DialogInterface>
        get() = alert {
            negativeButton(R.string.app_canceled) {
                dialogListener?.onDismiss?.invoke()
            }
            customView = createCustomView(vm.data)
        }

    fun createCustomView(data: Data): View {
        //returning view
    }
}
```

Also my DialogListener is sort of that:

```
interface DialogListener {

    var onDismiss: () -> Unit

    val onClick: (Data) -> Unit

    var onPostClick: (Data) -> Unit

}
```

And finally, in parent fragment we can use:

```
MyDialogFragment.create().show(childFragmentManager, MyDialogFragment::class.java.simpleName)
```

Hope it will help somebody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Android Documentation, [`Dialog` implements `DialogInterface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html). So all known subclasses of `Dialog` including `AlertDialog` implement that interface.

You can cast and return the result from the build as follows:

```
return alert {
    message = "Message"                   
    positiveButton("OK") {
        //stuff
    }
    negativeButton("NOT OK") {
        //stuff
    }
}.build() as Dialog
```

This will work but if Anko ever changes its implementation you will get a `ClassCastException`. To get a cleaner error you can use the following.

```
val dialogInterface = alert {
    message = "Message"                   
    positiveButton("OK") {
        //stuff
    }
    negativeButton("NOT OK") {
        //stuff
    }
}.build()
return (dialogInterface as? Dialog) ?: error("Anko DialogInterface is no longer backed by Android Dialog")
```

This gives you a more explicit error, but most likely won't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have dynamic UI then you can use `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your activity in manifest, look likes:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:configChanges="orientation">
...
</activity>
```